# Is CanvasJS compatible with Excel and making chart?

Tags: canvasjs

I was wondering if its capable of reading an excel file (ie. sample.xls) and making a chart based on that? If so can you provide a sample image and the source code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanvasJS doesn't currently support importing or exporting data in Microsoft Excel format. You’ll have to do the conversion to and from CanvasJS format.

Reference: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart

Answer (score -1):

use below code as reference of exporting data into excel

```
document.getElementById("downloadExcel").addEventListener("click", function(){
  downloadAsExcel({ filename: "chart-data", chart: chart })
});

function downloadAsExcel(args) {
  var dataPoints, filename;  
  filename = args.filename || 'chart-data';

  dataPoints = args.chart.data[0].dataPoints;
  dataPoints.unshift({x: "X Value", y: "Y-Value"});
  var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(dataPoints, {skipHeader:true, dateNF: 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss'});
  if(!ws['!cols']) ws['!cols'] = [];
  ws['!cols'][0] = { wch: 17 };
  var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, filename);
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename + ".xlsx");
}
```

reference link https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/7kqeprcs/ for exporting data in excel file.

If you want to download Multi series chart data in single excel file then refer https://jsfiddle.net/Root_Savaj/zmf6uqsv/ Link.